# Binding links within an ember helper

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-cli

I'm new to ember.js and ember-cli, all has been going well until I just tried to create my first custom helper.

I'm trying to loop through a model, displaying some image thumbnails on multiple rows within the page.

Everything seems to be working fine but I would like to try and bind the links.

Here's my custom helper:

```
import Ember from "ember";

export default Ember.Handlebars.makeBoundHelper(function(value, options) {

  var out = '';
  var b = 0;

  for (var i=0; i<value.length; i++) {
    b++;

    if(b === 1){
      out += '<div class="row">';
    }

    out += '<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 center" style="text-align:center;">\
    <div class="row center">\
    <div class="col-md-12 center">\
    <a href="photo/'+value[i]._data.id+'">\
    <img class="center" src="'+value[i]._data.thumb_url+'" />\
    </a>\
    </div>\
    </div>\
    <div class="row center">\
      <div class="col-md-6">'+value[i]._data.status+'</div>\
      <div class="col-md-6"></div>\
    </div>\
    </div>';

    if(b === 3){
      out += '</div><div class="row"><div class="col-md-12">&nbsp;</div></div>';
      b=0;
    }

  }

  return new Handlebars.SafeString(out);

});
```

I know that you can't use link-to directly inside a helper so I've been playing around with different options, with no luck.

The most success I had was trying to run link-to manually using something along the lines of:

```
Ember.Handlebars.helpers.linkTo.call('photo/1', 'photo.index', options);
```

But this hasn't been working out for me either.

Any tips? I fear I'm probably going about this in completely the wrong way

**Edit**

An example of the output I'm trying to achieve with a helper

```
<div class="row">
  <div>
    <a link><img></a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a link><img></a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a link><img></a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div>
    <a link><img></a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a link><img></a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a link><img></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably create an Ember Component instead of creating a Handlebars helper. With an Ember Component you can use `{{#linkTo}}` and all the bindings work.

Use the Ember component to create a virtual property `rows`, where you set the items
of each row; then you can iterate over the rows and items with regular `{{#each}}` inside of the component template.

The component code would look like this:

```
 App.SampleComponentComponent = Ember.Component.extend({ 
     rows : function() {
        var myRows = [];
        var elements = this.get('model');
        var b = -1;
        for(var i = 0; i<elements.length; i++) {
           if(i % 2 === 0) {
              b++;
              myRows[b] = [];
           }
        myRows[b][i%2] = elements[i];
     }
  return myRows;
  }.property('model'),
});
```

The component template would look like:

```
 <ul>
{{#each row in rows}}
  <li>
  <ol>
  {{#each item in row}}
    <li>{{item}}</li>
  {{/each}}
  </ol>
  </li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

You will have to pass the array of items to the component in the `model` paramater.

Working example in: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cowin/3/

The tutorial in http://emberjs.com/guides/components/ should help.

Comment: Ah ok I'll have another look into then although I was under the impression you can't use JS inside the component so I wouldn't be able to do the looping?

Comment: You can loop with `{{#each}}`

Comment: That's where my issue first came from. I need to do a custom loop to generate the output I've just added to the original question